Problemas de renderizado al correr proyecto de Angular con Ionic en producción (Angular 18, Ionic 7)
Estoy trabajando en una aplicación utilizando Angular 18 y Ionic 7, pero estoy enfrentando problemas al ejecutar el proyecto en modo de producción. En desarrollo, todo funciona correctamente, pero al correrlo en producción, algunos componentes y etiquetas de Ionic no se renderizan bien.
Lo que he hecho:
Configuración del proyecto en main.ts:
En lugar de usar el enfoque tradicional de importar IonicModule.forRoot(), en Angular 18 se usa bootstrapApplication con la siguiente configuración:
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy, provideRouter, withPreloading, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicRouteStrategy, provideIonicAngular } from '@ionic/angular/standalone';
import { routes } from './app/app.routes';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { getStorage, provideStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }, 
    provideIonicAngular({
      innerHTMLTemplatesEnabled: true // Activado para habilitar plantillas dentro del HTML
    }),
    provideRouter(routes, withPreloading(PreloadAllModules)),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
    provideHttpClient(),
  ],
});

Configuración de estilos y scripts:
Los estilos de Ionic están correctamente importados en la sección de styles en el archivo angular.json:
"styles": [
  "src/global.scss",
  "src/theme/variables.scss",
  "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/core.css",
  "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/ionic.bundle.css"
],
"scripts": []

Uso de Lazy Loading:
Estoy utilizando lazy loading para los módulos y no parece que haya problemas con la carga de módulos en producción. Sin embargo, los componentes de Ionic no se renderizan correctamente en la versión de producción.
lo que no ha funcionado:
Recompilación limpia: He ejecutado un build limpio con:
ionic build --prod --clean

Pero los problemas persisten en la versión de producción.
Errores en la consola: aparecen errores en la consola del navegador,sin embargo se pueden omitir pero tampoco no hace ningun efecto
 :host-context([dir=rtl]) .ion-float-start -> Unknown pseudo-class :host-context([object Object])
  .ion-float-start:dir(rtl) -> Unknown pseudo-class :dir

Configuración de optimización:
Activé las optimizaciones y buildOptimizer en la configuración de producción, pero los componentes siguen sin renderizarse correctamente:
"production": {
  "buildOptimizer": true,
  "optimization": true,
  "vendorChunk": false,
  "extractLicenses": true,
  "sourceMap": false,
  "namedChunks": false,
  "fileReplacements": [
    {
      "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
      "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
    }
  ],
  "outputHashing": "all"
}

Problemas con tree-shaking: No he encontrado que los componentes de Ionic sean eliminados por el tree-shaking, pero no estoy seguro si algunos de los recursos de Ionic no se están cargando correctamente en producción.
¿Alguien más ha tenido problemas similares en Angular 18 con Ionic? ¿Qué podría estar causando que los componentes de Ionic no se rendericen correctamente en producción? ¿Hay algo más que pueda probar para solucionar esto?
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.
PD: Tal vez puede ser que no se esta cargando un modulo, desconozco si tengo que cargar algún mas en el main.ts , ya que anteriormente usaba los módulos y se cargaba el modulo ionicModule en app.module.ts , y tal vez por ese tema no se ven las etiquetas .
